# Given two arrays of distinct integers A and B of size m and n, what is the lower-bound complexity for finding one common element?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have the following problem:

Given two arrays of distinct integers A and B of size m and n, what is the upper-bound complexity for finding the first common element? I can use at most O(k) memory in addition to the input arrays.

k is a constant (means that i can use only constant memory in addition to the input)

I've already asked this in another site:

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/lower-bound-complexities-for-finding-common-elements-between-two-unsorted-arrays

but didn't solved the problem

Comment: May be a lack of coffee that makes me ask, but `O(k)` where `k` is what?

Comment: Why do you care about the lower-bound Ω()? Such problems are usually expressed in terms of upper bound O().

Comment: Lower bound makes no sense for this task. with luck the first test is a hit. i think you want to know the upper bound (worst case)

Comment: Please tell me you know the difference between the lower-bound complexity of an algorithm and the complexity of the optimal algorithm on the same problem

Comment: I just saw that the question was closed while I was typing my answer. I recommend you update this question to include the information in your original post on CS to get this question reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to have a crack at the second problem in your [original post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/lower-bound-complexities-for-finding-common-elements-between-two-unsorted-arrays) on CS because I'm not sure your summarization of the problem is the best one.

> Given two unsorted arrays of distinct integers, ***A*** and ***B***, of size *m* and *n*; knowing that common elements between the arrays have the same relative order in both arrays and that for every couple of consecutive common elements, their distance is at most *k*(constant), determine all the common elements between the two arrays maintaining their relative order and using at most *O(k)* memory in addition to the input arrays.

I'll again use a heap as mentioned in the comments and in your edit on the original question, but this time we need only one heap.

Notice that in order to determine whether element ***A***[i] has a match in array ***B***, we need only check elements ***B***[i-k]..***B***[i+k]. Construct a heap ***B'*** of these elements in *O(k)* time and 2k+1 = *O(k)* space using heapify on the subarray of ***B***. Determining whether there exists a match for ***A***[i] in ***B'*** takes *O(log k)*. We then iterate through ***A*** for i=1..m, updating ***B'*** and checking for a match to ***A***[i]. This maintains the relative order in the output. To determine whether there are matches for all *m* elements in ***A*** takes *O(km log k)*, or ***O(m)*** time.

Notes:

- Obviously you should iterate through the smaller array, putting the elements of the larger array into the heap. I've assumed throughout that *m* <= *n*.
- You should never have to put more than k+1 elements into the heap at a time, which will happen when checking the first element of A. The heap can potentially grow to be up to 2k+1 elements while checking some element ***A***[i], k < i < m-k. Outside of this range, the heap will always be smaller.
- Once i is in the range k < i < m-k, if there is no match on the current index you will only have to add one element and delete one element from the heap to check the next index.
- If there **is** a match, say at ***A***[i] and ***B***[j], you still have to add at most one element, but you can remove all of the elements from the heap with index less than or equal to j (since we know that elements have the same relative order, so ***A***[i+1] will not match anything before ***B***[j+1]). At some point it may become more efficient to simply rebuild the heap with elements ***B***[j+1]..***B***[i+k].
- Once our heap has grown to its maximum size of 2k+1, we are always removing at least as many elements as we are adding. Therefore our heap will never be larger than 2k+1.